# python path django

Tags: python, django, path

How can I add something to my "Pythonpath".

Where exactly are the files located, I have to change to add to my pythonpath?

What exactly do I add to my Pythonpath?

If Python calls:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/

But I want it to call

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages

What do I need to add to make it work.

Strange is that I already used the django-admin.py for a startproject ccommand.
But now it does not find it.

Is there a way to clean up my ALL my Python, Django so I can restart with a fresh version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
```

`sys.path` is the list of search path for modules.

if you want a module to be loaded from `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages` instead of `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/`

you just need to make sure that `site-packages` search path comes before the `Contents` in sys.path

you can set the python path using `PYTHONPATH` environment variable

ex: (on a linux system)

```
export PYTHONPATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

Comment: Thanks a million! If I set the PYTHONPATH by: sys.path.append("/PATH"), where is it written to?

And your export PYTHONPATH code above: Where do I write it to...

Thanks a lot again..

Comment: export PYTHONPATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH, set this line in .bashrc file in your home folder.

if you are updating sys.path, you can set that line in any python file but make sure that sys.path is executed before any import happens.

specifically for django you can add `sys.path.append` at the top of manage.py file

Answer (score -4):

This tutorial will probably work for you if you want to remove an old version:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/install/#removing-old-versions-of-django