# Error setting up debugger for Django VS Code

Tags: python, django

So i'm starting to explore Django in VS Code using a tutorial and got this error when running the debugger on manage.py:

Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'hello' File "C:\Users...\Desktop\django_test\manage.py", line 15, in  execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

For context the name of my project is web_project which is essentially a skeleton, and "hello" refers to an app made with mostly just a skeleton. I have tried three main things that were unsuccessful: modifying launch.json, modifying manage.py, and modifying the file structure. None of which have worked. Any advice you have would be appreciated.

My manage.py file:

```js
import os
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'web_project.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

My launch.json:

```js
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
                "--noreload",

            ],
            "django": true
        },
}
```

The file structure:
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/33vgX.png

Comment: is PYTHONPATH in your environment?

Comment: It is, just double checked.

Comment: Looking at your file structure..you shouldn't move the settings.py file out of the web_project directory. That's where manage.py is looking for it. Can you move it back and see if you can run the Django app from outside of VS code? That way you'll know if this has something to do with VS Code or not. Run manage.py runserver from the command line according to the instructions on the Django documentation page.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same error. The problem was **PYTHONPATH** which must be defined or updated. my problem was solved by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177715/python-path-django/3177844#3177844)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the app to the INSTALLED_APPS list? Please add it if  it is not added in settings.py file. Django looks for the installed apps list one after the other. Also, move the settings.py file to the web_project directory.

Comment: It is listed in the INSTALLED_APPS list as: ' hello',

Comment: Try moving the settings.py file to web_project directory. settings.py, wsgi.py, urls.py should be in the same level.

Comment: I moved settings.py to the web_project directory and got a similar error instead for settings. py :"Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'web_project.settings'
File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\django_test\manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you must have checked the DEBUG option. Just uncheck it, just like the option circled in the picture.
(**Uncaught Exceptions**).

[Like this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5ieN.png)